# R matrix getting row and column number and actual value

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a matrix as below

```
 B = matrix( 
   c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), 
   nrow=3, 
   ncol=2)

 B             # B has 3 rows and 2 columns 
 #    [,1] [,2] 
 #[1,]    2    1 
 #[2,]    4    5 
 #[3,]    3    7
```

I would like to create a data.frame with 3 columns: row number, column number and actual value from above matrix. I am thinking of writing 2 for loops. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

The output that i want (i am showing only first 2 rows below)

```
rownum columnnum value
1 1 2
1 2 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
cbind(c(row(B)), c(col(B)), c(B))
```

Or

```
library(reshape2)
melt(B)
```

As per @nicola's comments, the output needed may be in the row-major order.  In that case, take the transpose of the matrix and do the same

```
TB <- t(B)
cbind(rownum = c(col(TB)), colnum = c(row(TB)), value = c(TB))
```

Comment: It seems that he wants the output following the row-major order; if so, `TB<-t(B) ; cbind(rownum=c(col(TB)),colnum= c(row(TB)), value=c(TB))` may be better. Also, set column names of the resulting object (btw, +1 of course).

Comment: @nicola Thanks, I thought the OP had a typo or so.

Answer (score 0):

`data.frame(which(B==B, arr.ind=TRUE), value=as.vector(B))`

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.